# AngularJS event not firing inside interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have trouble to fire an event inside the interval the code looks like following.

```
buildApp.controller("StatusCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $interval, CONSTANTS) {
    $rootScope.$on('changestatus', function(event,data) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.id = data.id;
        //fire event if got success or terminate if reached 10 minute of try

        $scope.getstatus = function(){
            var req = {
                method : 'GET',
                url:  CONSTANTS.API.HTTPSERVER + CONSTANTS.API.BASEURL + CONSTANTS.API.BUILD.SELF + CONSTANTS.API.BUILD.GETCURRENTSTATUS + $rootScope.id
            }
            $http(req).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.status = data.status;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $rootScope.status = "failed";
            });
        };

        var promise;
        promise = $interval(function () {
            $scope.getstatus();
            if ($rootScope.status == "BuildSucceeded") {
                console.log($rootScope.status);
                $interval.cancel(promise);
                $rootScope.$emit('buildinfo', {id: $scope.id});
            }
            else if (promise == 600000) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $interval.cancel(promise);
            }
        }, 30000);
    })
});
```

The quick explanation about code is i am hitting an api at regular 30 second interval if i got success message i will fire other event but even with success the second event not get fired `$rootScope.$emit('buildinfo', {id: $scope.id});` this code is not executing successfully.